# How to close Xsocket client connection using the C# client API in XSockets

Tags: c#, xsockets.net

My Xsocket client:

```
Connect(Object module)
    {
        var socket = new XSocketClient("wss://localhost:46000/SocketController", "https://somesites.com", CertUtils.RetrieveX509Certificate2());
        socket.Open();                
        var list = new List<Task>();
        list.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => socket.Send(new { Module = module, Action = "GetStatus" }, "Exec")));
        list.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => socket.Send(new { Module = module, Action = "GetStatus" }, "Exec")));
        list.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => socket.Send(dataupdate, "Update")));
        Task.WaitAll(list.ToArray());
    }
```

Call 1:
Connect(....)   /*Sucess*/

Call 2:
Connect(....)  /*System execption: You cant send messages when not conencted to the server*/

Call 3:
Connect(....)  /*System execption: You cant send messages when not conencted to the server*/

Comment: socket.close() is not closing this client connection

Comment: Is it possible to call `socket.Dispose()`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are referring to XScokets.NET. If so you can read the documentation on [GitBook](https://uffebjorklund.gitbooks.io/xsockets-net-5/content/clients/csharp/connect.html). If you are using a XSockets library in C# that I am not familiar with you can ignore this answer :)

Your connection looks a bit strange since certificates are added [like this](https://uffebjorklund.gitbooks.io/xsockets-net-5/content/clients/csharp/configure_the_connection.html)

Edit: if you are using XSockets.NET, what version are you using?